# CQRS where to put domain / business logic

Tags: asp.net-mvc, domain-driven-design, cqrs, solid-principles

I am developing framework for MVC application. As part of framework, I have created a dummy application. I am following Onion Architecture and SOLID principle with CQRS. This is my first project with MVC and CQRS. I am also following Chain of Responsibility in CQRS.

At present I am not sure about the part where I should keep business logic.

Example.
I have Command of Debit Account from bank account. I have created command as DebitAccount and handler as IDebitAccountHandler. IDebitAccountHandler will be implemented in Infrastructure layer with required dependencies as DebitAccountHandler.

Here I have core logic of checking balance before debiting account. I would want to implement this in Core as it does not change with Infrastructure.

Now where should I implement this logic and also load required dependencies. My commands are interfaces without any method body, also they contain only on method of Handle/Execute.

I feel this is newbie question and arising due to my limited understanding of patterns.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the domain, but in general , you could implement  the checking in domain models(like Account) or a domain service(if this involves several models) then invoke the checker in handler.

Answer (score 2):

Each command represents a use case. A command handler doesn't contain any logic; it takes care of infrastructural concerns, and delegates to the domain.

You want all your logic to be in your domain model: aggregates, entities, value objects, services... In your example, the logic would be encapsulated by the `Account` aggregate.

```
public class Account
{
    private Balance _balance;

    public void Debit(Amount amount) 
    {
        if (_balance.IsSufficient())
                // debit..
    }
}
```