# Where do I put business logic when implementing CQRS pattern using Mediatr in a .Net Clean Architecture application?

Tags: asp.net, .net, cqrs, clean-architecture

Currently I'm facing a trouble implementing the business logic using clean architecture and cqrs pattern. I'm using Mediatr and AutoMapper to do that. I have the following structure for the cqrs pattern

- ApplicationCore

  - DTOs

    - SmartphoneDto.cs
  - Features

    - Smartphone

      - Handlers

        - Commands

          - AddSmartphoneCommandHandler.cs
        - Queries
      - Requests

        - Commands

          - AddSmartphoneCommand.cs
        - Queries
- DomainCore

  - Smartphone.cs

And the following classes:

SmartphoneDto.cs

```
public class SmartphoneDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string serialnumber { get; set; }
}
```

Domain Entity Smartphone.cs

```
public class Smartphone
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string imei { get; set; }
    public string serialnumber { get; set; }
    public string calculatedValue { get; set; }

}
```

AddSmartphoneCommand.cs

```
public class AddSmartphoneCommand : IRequest<bool>
{
    public SmartphoneDto SmartphoneDto { get; set; }
}
```

AddSmartphoneCommandHandler.cs

```
public class AddSmartphoneCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<AddSmartphoneCommand, bool>
{
    private readonly ISmartphoneRepository _smartphoneRepository;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public AddSmartphoneCommandHandler(ISmartphoneRepository smartphoneRepository, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _smartphoneRepository = smartphoneRepository;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public async Task<bool> Handle(AddSmartphoneCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var smartphone = _mapper.Map<Smartphone>(request.SmartphoneDto);
        //Business Logic???
        await _smartphoneRepository.AddAsync(smartphone);

        return true;
    }
}
```

And I´m not sure where the business logic goes, I've read different post with suggestions like these but with no possible solutions or a clear example:

[Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76939605/where-do-i-place-complex-business-logic-when-using-the-clean-architecture-and-me) As I understood we can put business logic in a external class that works as a service called from the handle method of the command handler

[Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19212372/cqrs-where-to-put-domain-business-logic) But in this post shows that the command handler doesn't have to contain any logic.

Due to my confusion, I've thinked put the business logic as follow:

```
{
    private readonly ISmartphoneRepository _smartphoneRepository;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public AddSmartphoneCommandHandler(ISmartphoneRepository smartphoneRepository, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _smartphoneRepository = smartphoneRepository;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public async Task<bool> Handle(AddSmartphoneCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var smartphone = _mapper.Map<Smartphone>(request.SmartphoneDto);

        #region businesslogic
        //All the business logic in this place
        smartphone.imei = someApi.GetAsync("someurl", smartphone.serialnumber);
        smartphone.calculatedValue = (smartphone.serialnumber - smartphone.imei) * 0.05;
        //end business logic
        #endregion

        await _smartphoneRepository.AddAsync(smartphone);

        return true;
    }
}
```

What would be the correct place in the structure to put that kind of business logic?

Answer (score 0):

Commands and Queries should be under the Application Layer.

#### DEPENDENCIES BETWEEN LAYERS:

- Domain layer:
  Doesn't depend on any layer.
  **Contains**: Entities, Aggregates, Value Objects, Repositories contracts.
- Application layer:
  Depends on the Domain and Infrastructure layers.
  **Contains**: CQRS, Use Cases, API contracts & implementations.
- Infrastructure layer:
  Depends on the Domain layer.
  **Contains**: Repositories implementation, ORMs (e.g., Entity Framework), Cryptography, Logging, etc.
- Presentation layer:
  Depends on the Application layer.

Answer (score 0):

The best place for business logic is in the domain layer itself.

Your domain objects are currently what we call "anemic" models, meaning they have no encapsulation whatsoever (just a bag of properties with getters and setters that don't enforce any business rules).

It sounds like setting the `imei` and perhaps the `serialnumber` should update the `calculatedValue`. The code can be moved to the domain by encapsulating the logic in a computed property, like so:

```
public class Smartphone
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string serialnumber { get; set; }
    public string imei { get; set; }
    public string calculatedValue => (this.serialnumber - this.imei) * 0.05;
}
```

This is one way to do it. There is a lot more you could encapsulate into the `Smartphone` class but that's a start.